# To get voltage signal with pyusb through USB device

Tags: python, pyusb

I am making a Python code to get voltage signal through USB port with "DIGITAL ICP USB SIGNAL CONDITIONER Model 485B39". Now I encountered a following error. But I am not sure how to deal with it. I would appreciate it if someone could support me.

The error encountered is :

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 233.13763.11)
 DEVICE ID 29da:000a on Bus 001 Address 015 =================
 bLength                :   0x12 (18 bytes)
 bDescriptorType        :    0x1 Device
 bcdUSB                 :  0x200 USB 2.0
 bDeviceClass           :    0x0 Specified at interface
 bDeviceSubClass        :    0x0
 bDeviceProtocol        :    0x0
 bMaxPacketSize0        :    0x8 (8 bytes)
 idVendor               : 0x29da
 idProduct              : 0x000a
 bcdDevice              :  0x100 Device 1.0
 iManufacturer          :    0x1 Digiducer.com 
 iProduct               :    0x2 485B39 200212708071760811861230228
 iSerialNumber          :    0x3 002127    200212708071760811861230228
 bNumConfigurations     :    0x1
  CONFIGURATION 1: 40 mA ===================================
   bLength              :    0x9 (9 bytes)
   bDescriptorType      :    0x2 Configuration
   wTotalLength         :   0xbd (189 bytes)
   bNumInterfaces       :    0x2
   bConfigurationValue  :    0x1
   iConfiguration       :    0x0 
   bmAttributes         :   0x80 Bus Powered
   bMaxPower            :   0x14 (40 mA)
    INTERFACE 0: Audio =====================================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x0
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x0
     bInterfaceClass    :    0x1 Audio
     bInterfaceSubClass :    0x1
     bInterfaceProtocol :    0x0
     iInterface         :    0x0 
    INTERFACE 1: Audio =====================================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x1
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x0
     bInterfaceClass    :    0x1 Audio
     bInterfaceSubClass :    0x2
     bInterfaceProtocol :    0x0
     iInterface         :    0x0 
    INTERFACE 1, 1: Audio ==================================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x1
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x1
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x1
     bInterfaceClass    :    0x1 Audio
     bInterfaceSubClass :    0x2
     bInterfaceProtocol :    0x0
     iInterface         :    0x0
      ENDPOINT 0x81: Isochronous IN ========================
       bLength          :    0x9 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0xd Isochronous
       wMaxPacketSize   :   0xc0 (192 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x1
    INTERFACE 1, 2: Audio ==================================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x1
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x2
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x1
     bInterfaceClass    :    0x1 Audio
     bInterfaceSubClass :    0x2
     bInterfaceProtocol :    0x0
     iInterface         :    0x0 
      ENDPOINT 0x81: Isochronous IN ========================
       bLength          :    0x9 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0xd Isochronous
       wMaxPacketSize   :  0x120 (288 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.3.3\plugins\python-        ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1534, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:\Users\sai\PycharmProjects\Voltage_signal_acq\000_wo_def_for_Ch01.py", line 26, in <module>
    usb.util.claim_interface(dev, interface_number)
  File "C:\Users\sai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\usb\util.py", line 207, in claim_interface
    device._ctx.managed_claim_interface(device, interface)
  File "C:\Users\sai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 178, in managed_claim_interface
    self.backend.claim_interface(self.handle, i)
  File "C:\Users\sai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-    packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 829, in claim_interface
_check(self.lib.libusb_claim_interface(dev_handle.handle, intf))
  File "C:\Users\sai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 600, in _check
    raise NotImplementedError(_strerror(ret))
NotImplementedError: Operation not supported or unimplemented on this platform
```

python-BaseException
Process finished with exit code 1

The current code is:

```
import usb.core
import usb.util

# Find the USB device
vendor_id = 0x29DA
product_id = 0x000A

dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=vendor_id, idProduct=product_id)
if dev is None:
    raise ValueError('Device not found')
print(dev)

# Set the active configuration
dev.set_configuration()

# Interface numbers and alternate settings for each channel
CHANNEL_1_INTERFACE_NUMBER = 0x1
CHANNEL_1_ALTERNATE_SETTING = 0x1

interface_number = CHANNEL_1_INTERFACE_NUMBER
alternate_setting = CHANNEL_1_ALTERNATE_SETTING

# Assuming the endpoint address for both channels is 0x81, you would read from it
endpoint_address = 0x81

usb.util.claim_interface(dev, interface_number)
# Set the alternate setting for the interface
dev.set_interface_altsetting(interface_number, alternate_setting)`
```

References :
OS : Windows10
USB driver :libusbK

I have already tried below. But

```
try:
    dev.detach_kernel_driver(interface_number)
except usb.core.USBError as e:
    print("Error detaching kernel driver: ", e)
```

Error encountered :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sai\PycharmProjects\Voltage_signal_acq\000_wo_def_for_Ch01.py", line 26, in <module>
    usb.util.claim_interface(dev, interface_number)
  File "C:\Users\sai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\usb\util.py", line 207, in claim_interface
    device._ctx.managed_claim_interface(device, interface)
  File "C:\Users\sai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 178, in managed_claim_interface
    self.backend.claim_interface(self.handle, i)
  File "C:\Users\sai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 829, in claim_interface
_check(self.lib.libusb_claim_interface(dev_handle.handle, intf))
  File "C:\Users\sai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 600, in _check
    raise NotImplementedError(_strerror(ret))
NotImplementedError: Operation not supported or unimplemented on this platform
```

Comment: Looks like something is trying to be done with libusb "behind the scenes" but libusb probably only supports that thing on Linux.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Actually libusb is likely to be supported by Windows. In this case, the issues was that the device was audio device. So the library of sounddevice became a countermeasure on it.